# Computer-to-Computer network between OS X and Linux

Tags: linux, macos, mac, wireless-networking, wpa-supplicant

I want to make a connection point to point via wifi between Mac and Linux.

What I did was:

1. I have created Computer-To-Computer network in OS X
2. I have set manually an ip address for Mac, 10.0.0.1/255.255.255.0
3. I set static ip in Linux, 10.0.0.2/255.255.255.0
4. Trying to connect from linux to OS X with wpa_supplicant

But wpa_supplicant just can not connect to the network created by OS X., it stopped by time out.

What I'm trying to do is make a connection via WIFI without using a rounter.

Comment: And what error do you see? What encryption are you using?

Comment: What kind of connection is "Computer-to-Computer" in OSX? Ad hoc network? Is the SSID hidden? What encryption are you using? Can you see the network from the Linux machine?

Comment: I'm not using any encryption, just plain connection. I fixed creating an access point from linux side, so now my Mac connects fine. Thank you guys anyway.